# Cann't write text to console after change window's focus

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-console

Console appear, but I cann't write something in this console.

Sometimes, I cann't write text right away after program starting.
Sometimes, I can write text right away after program starting, but when I change focus on explorer and then return back on console - input doesn't work.

I don't have any exception!

```
Console.Write("Input path to file CSV: ");
string pathToCSV = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Your whole code consists only of those 2 lines in the `Main` method? If not please post an MVCE.

Comment: This code works as expected for me and changing the focus does not do anything.
Can you add more code please ?

Comment: You might want to look into [What does it do exactly if I click in the window of cmd?](https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd)

Comment: Guys, thanks for helping. In my opinion, problem was in Caramba Switcher (https://caramba-switcher.com/). This programm changes keyboard layout fast and it leads to problem. I have turned off Switcher and problem disappeared.